What's the logic in exiting early on failure in blocks and subshells in Bash?
In Bash blocks {} and subshells () the exit early doesn't work if there is an OR condition following it. Take for example
set -e
{ echo a; false; echo b; } || echo c 

prints
a
b

and
set -e
{ echo a; false; echo b; false;} || echo c 

prints
a
b
c

It seems to take the last executed command's exit code only. While this makes sense, given a semicolon instead of && is used, I'd expect the set -e to still make it exit on the first false and execute the error handling echo c code.
Using && instead of ; does make it work, but that makes it messy when having multiple line blocks. Adding in set -e at the start of the block/subshell also has no effect.
The reason this confuses me is because
set -e
{ echo a; false; echo b; }

prints
a

which means the exit-on-failure works when there's no || code following it. So I'd expect this to be the case with || code following it, executing it after the first failure in the block. Is there no way to achieve that without appending && after each line in the block?

That's the awkwardly expected behavior of set -e in conditionals; or else a simple if false; then echo foo; else echo bar; fi would kill the script

@Fravadona would you care to write an answer that says what you're saying here in the comment?

@MarcusMüller There's probably a lot of dups of this question, with better explanations ;-)

This is BashFAQ 105: Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?

@ilkkachu This one won't output "baz": true && { false; echo baz; }. So I would say that if the return status is checked by a conditional then set -e won't kick in.

@Fravadona, right, I meant being under the testing part of a conditional anywhere. But note that in e.g. { false; echo x; } && echo y;, the exit status of false isn't exactly checked by any conditional (since echo x runs unconditionally after the semicolon), but it's still under the left-hand side of the &&  so set -e doesn't kick in. It works similarly even if there's subshells or functions in between.

Anyway, the point is that it's no use expecting it to be useful. One might hope, but it's in vain. It's a FAQ exactly because it looks way more useful at first glance than it actually is. Just forget about set -e, test manually and be happier. :)

I never understood the aversion to set -e up until now. true && {false; something} behaving differently than {false; something} && true under set -e is a fantastic illustration of why to avoid it. You try to avoid the "unchecked error happened" case, but invite a complete host of corner cases not covered in a sensible way by the design of what set -e does.
